# How to move child-entities between parent entities in Doctrine?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have such a code:

```
/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="Record")
 */
class Record
{
public function setParent(Parent $p)
{
    $this->parent = $p;
}
/** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue **/
private $id;
/**  @ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Domain\Model\Parent", inversedBy="childs")
 * @JoinColumn(name="parent" referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
 */
private $parent;
}
```

and the parent class:

```
/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="Parent")
 **/
class Parent
{


 public function getChilds():array
    {
    return $this->childs->getValues();
    }
/** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue **/
private $id;
    /**
    * @OneToMany(targetEntity="\Domain\Model\Record, mappedBy="parent")
    */
    private $childs;
}
```

I want to move childs from one parent to another. When I do this in that way, there is no affect of database:

```
public function move(Parent $from, Parent $to)
{
    foreach($from->getChilds() as $child)
    {
    $child->setParent($to);
    $entityManager->persist($child);
    }
}
```

How should I do this? Why does doctrine ignore the changes?

Comment: You need $entityManager->flush(); just after the foreach block.  https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-associations.html#working-with-associations